# release-channel attribute in terraform for GKE cluster creation

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/release-channels
offers to specify a release-channel on cluster creation for  automatic upgrades of the cluster.

```
gcloud alpha container clusters create [CLUSTER-NAME] \
      --zone [ZONE] \
      [ADDITIONAL-FLAGS] \
      --release-channel rapid
```

It seems not possible with Terraform.
It would be nice to have this feature in terraform too, right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the release-channel feature is still in beta

It'd be worth raising in https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google-beta (a variant of the Google provider, which "is now necessary to be able to configure products and features that are in beta", according to https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/version_2_upgrade.html#the-google-beta-provider)

Answer (score 0):

When I need a resource that hasn't made it to the google provider yet I usually just create a wrapper module that calls the gcloud command.  Here's an example:

https://github.com/rojopolis/terraform-google-filestore